# Negative transformation of an image in C

Tags: c, image-processing, bmp

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < conio.h >
#include < stdlib.h >
#include < process.h >
#include < string.h >
#include < math.h >

int count = 0;

typedef struct bitmap24 {
    unsigned char header[54];
    unsigned char * pixels;
}BMP;

void readBMP(char * filename) {
    int i;
    FILE * f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    FILE * f1 = fopen("save.bmp", "wb");
    FILE * pixelVals = fopen("vals.dat", "w");
    unsigned char bmppad[3] = {
        0,
        0,
        0
    };
    if (!f) {
        printf("Could not read file!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    unsigned char info[54];
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f);
    int width = * (int * ) & info[18];
    int height = * (int * ) & info[22];

    unsigned char * img = NULL;
    if (img)
        free(img);
    img = (unsigned char * ) malloc(3 * width * height);
    memset(img, 0, sizeof(img));

    fwrite(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f1);

    int length = width * height;
    unsigned long int image[10000][3];

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        image[i][2] = getc(f); // blue
        image[i][1] = getc(f); // green
        image[i][0] = getc(f); // red

        img[count] = 255 - (unsigned char) image[i][0];
        //img[count] = 10*(unsigned char)log10((double)image[i][0]+1);
        count += 1;
        img[count] = 255 - (unsigned char) image[i][2];
        //img[count] = 10*(unsigned char)log10((double)image[i][3]+1);
        count += 1;
        img[count] = 255 - (unsigned char) image[i][2];
        //img[count] = 10*(unsigned char)log10((double)image[i][2]+1);
        count += 1;

        printf("pixel %d : [%d,%d,%d]\n", i + 1, image[i][0], image[i][4], image[i][2]);
        fprintf(pixelVals, "pixel %d : [%d,%d,%d]\n", i + 1, image[i][0], image[i][5], image[i][2]);
    }

    for (i = height - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        fwrite(img + (width * (height - i - 1) * 3), 3, width, f1);
        fwrite(bmppad, 1, (4 - (width * 3) % 4) % 4, f1);
    }

    fclose(f);
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(pixelVals);
}

void main() {
    char * fileName = "bitgray.bmp";
    readBMP(fileName);
    getch();
}
```

I am not getting the correct result when the image is saved. I am using 24bit bmp image of dimensions 114 X 81. The image was coming out to be inverted initially but that issue was solved. But I am still getting a slanted image. I know the problem is in the last 'for' loop.
How should I solve it ?

[image: Original Image]

[image: Negative Image]

Comment: @paddy In the loop `fwrite(img+(width*(height - i - 1)*3), 3, width, f1);` stores the pixel values of the scan line and the second line `fwrite(bmppad, 1, (4-(width * 3)%4)%4, f1);` adds the padding to it which is 2 in this case. 
I have done what you mentioned but still I am getting the same answer ... !

Comment: Yes, because you still don't read the image in correctly.  If you don't read it right, you can't write it right, right?

Comment: @paddy You are right. I checked it on matlab and got very different result.

Comment: but I can't find the error in the reading of the pixels ...

Comment: Yet I have stated quite clearly in my answer, that at the end of every scan line you must read and discard the padding bytes.  Your code completely ignores the concept of a scan line and reads a contiguous block of `width*height*3` bytes.  I don't think I can be more specific than that.  As a side-note, if you just want straight inversion there is no need to read into a buffer.  You could simply read, invert and write out every byte from the input file until EOF.  I don't think there is a requirement that the padding bytes be zero...  *ie* it's okay to invert them.

Answer (score 5):

Bitmap scanlines are padded to 4-byte boundary.  So you need to add an extra two bytes so that the row is divisible by 4.  At the moment, you have `114 * 3 = 342` bytes of pixel data per line.  The next number divisible by 4 is `344`.

So, at the end of reading each line, just read an extra two bytes and discard them.

In general, you can work out the extra bytes like this:

```
extra = (alignment - ((width * bytesPerPixel) % alignment)) % alignment;
```

Where in this case `alignment` is 4.

From memory, there is a field in the header that should contain the value of the full scanwidth (`width * bytesPerPixel + extra`), but it's a good idea not to expect it to be correct because you can calculate it easily.

You must also be aware of this padding rule when you save a bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Your second *for* loop looks strange. I believe it should be:

```
for(i = 0; i < height;  i++) {...}
```

or:

```
for(i = height-1; i >= 0;  i--) {...}
```